# Microsoft Teams Connector: HttpPOST on MessageCard returns ODataContentTypeException

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, connector, office365connectors

We set up a new Microsoft Teams Connector and successfully set the settings to POST cards to the received WebhookUrl.
In the body that we send, we included the option to make HttpPost requests to a defined target URL (using ngrok.io tunnel for development). You can see the sent messageCard below:

```
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
    "summary": "Card \"Test card\"",
    "themeColor": "0078D7",
    "title": "Card created: \"Just another test\"",
    "potentialAction": [
        {
            "@type": "ActionCard",
            "name": "Add a comment",
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "@type": "TextInput",
                    "id": "comment",
                    "isMultiline": true,
                    "title": "Enter your comment"
                }
            ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "@type": "HttpPOST",
                    "name": "Ok",
                    "target": "https://dd846f80.ngrok.io/teamshooks/actions",
                    "body": "{\"Comment\":\"This is a test\"}",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        {
                            "aw-teamid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The card is displayed correctly in the channel in Microsoft Teams.
When a user clicks on this button, to make a HttpPOST to the specified url, we never receive the request on our side but can see that Microsoft returns the following response to the internal "executeAction" request:

The request was sent on: Fri, 13 Dec 2019 11:09:48 GMT

```
{
   "status": "Failed",
   "actionId": "c520b20a-3e04-4e21-b4fd-c3a2f760c533",
   "properties":
      { 
          "displayMessage": "<p>Could not complete the requested action. Please try again later.</p>\n",
          "errorCode": "ODataContentTypeException"
      }
}
```

The following settings are set-up in the Connectors Developer Dashboard (and in the manifest.json):

---

```
"connectors": [
    {
      "connectorId": "6b2ba9c0-7c0a-4524-9e6d-64f061350aa4",
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ],
      "configurationUrl": "https://dd846f80.ngrok.io/msteams/aworkConnector/config.html"
    }
  ]
```

```
 "validDomains": [
    "dd846f80.ngrok.io"
  ]
```

Do you want to enable actions on your Connector cards? - Yes

Actions Url: https://dd846f80.ngrok.io/teamshooks/actions

---

Is there anything we are currently doing wrong or does anyone have an idea on how to solve the returned ODataContentTypeException? We need to receive the request in our backend, in order to integrate Micorsoft Teams into our software.

Comment: Duplicate of this [github question](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/1221). Please use the other github question asked by you to track this.

Answer (score 0):

Upload the manifest.json from an admin account, and add the ngrok url in the valid domains. Microsoft teams have blocked custom connectors from performing actions when uploaded by non admin users